Determine the (shortest) distance between the point $(−5, 1, −2)$ and the line given by the equations $5y+4-z=0$ and $5x-2z+13=0$.
The problem:
Determine the (shortest) distance between the point $(−5, 1, −2)$ and the line given by the equations $5y+4-z=0$ and $5x-2z+13=0$.
The solution:
$\sqrt{\frac{221}{30}}$
What I have tried:
$P_0=(x_0, y_0, z_0)=(-5, 1, -2)$
$0x+5y-z \rightarrow 0i+5j-k$
$5x+0y-2z \rightarrow 5i+0j-2k$
$(-0i+5j-k) \times (5i+0j-2k) = \begin{vmatrix} 0 & 5 & -1\\\ 5 & 0 & -2 \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 5 & -1\\\ 0 & -2 \end{vmatrix}i-\begin{vmatrix} 0 & -1\\\ 5 & -2 \end{vmatrix}j+\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 5 \\\ 5 & 0 \end{vmatrix}k=5(-2)i + 5j + 0k=$
$= -10i+5j+0k$
We can represent the distance from $P_0$ to $Ax+By+Cz-D=-10x+5y+0z=$ as
$s=\frac{\vert Ax_0+By_0+Cz_0-D \vert}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$
After having plugged in everything I get $\frac{11}{\sqrt{5}}$, which is not the right answer.
My question:
I figure the last formula for finding the distance is the way to go. But where I think I am going wrong is when I try to figure out the line for the given equations. How can I find it? Because using the cross-section of those equations just does not seem right but it is the only thing that I could come up with so that is what I tried.

Your line is the intersection of the two planes. I don't understand why you would want to find another plane.

What method can I use to find the line?

Find two points in the intersection, say $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. The parameterised version of your line will be $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, $(x_1,y_1,z_1)+\lambda(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_2,z_2-z_2)$.

$A_1x+B_1y+C_1z=D_1 \Rightarrow 0x+5y-z=-4$ and $A_2x+B_2y+C_2z=D_2 \Rightarrow 5x+0y-2z=-13$, then for any real value of the real number $\lambda$, the equation $A_1x+B_1y+C_1z-D_1+ \lambda(A_2x+B_2y+C_2z-D_2)=0 \Rightarrow 5y-z+4+\lambda (5x-2z+13)=0$ represents a plane in the pencil. The equation of the required plane is then acquired by figuring out $\lambda$, right? How do I find $\lambda$?

$$5y+4−z=0 \implies z = 5y + 4$$
$$5x−2z+13=0 \implies z = \frac{5x + 13}{2}$$
Equating the two expressions for $z$ gives $5y + 4 = \frac{5x + 13}{2}$, or $y = \frac{x + 1}{2}$.
This gives us a parameterization of the line: Each point has the form $(x, \frac{x + 1}{2}, \frac{5x + 13}{2})$.
The distance between each point on the line and the point $(-5, 1, -2)$ is:
$$f(x) = \sqrt{(x + 5)^2 + \left(\frac{x + 1}{2} - 1\right)^2 + \left(\frac{5x + 13}{2} + 2\right)^2}$$
$$= \frac{\sqrt{30x^2 + 208x + 390}}{2}$$
And we need to find the minimum value of this difference.  Recall that $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ has its vertex (minimum if $a > 0$, maximum if $a < 0$) at $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$.  In this case, that works out to $x = -\frac{52}{15}$, for which $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{221}{30}} \approx 2.71416$.

Okay, this is making a lot of sense to me up until the figuring out of the variable $x$. Where is $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$ coming from? The solution, i.e. the distance, is not $\sqrt{\frac{3821}{126}}.$

Sorry, my bad. I made a typo in my original post. The problem should have read: "Determine the (shortest) distance between the point $(−5, 1, −2)$ and the line given by the equations $5y+4-z=0$ and $5x-2z+13=0$."

Okay, following your method. I get this: Each point on the line has the form $(x, \frac{x+1}{2}, \frac{5x+13}{2})$. The distance between each point on the line and the point $(-5, 1, -2)$ is $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{15x^2+104x+195}{2}}$. Minimum is at $x=-\frac{52}{15}$, for which $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{221}{30}}$. I got the right answer. But I got the x-value for where a minimum value can be found with the help of WolframAlpha. I do not understand how it is you went about it.

First off, parameterize the line.
"...the line given by the equations $5y+4−z=0$ and $x−2z+13=0$" refers to the line which is in the intersection of these two planes.
Check that the points $(-15,-1,-1)$ and $(-25,-2,-6)$ satisfy equation of both the planes and hence, they lie on your line. The direction ratios are given by $(-15,-1,-1)-(-25,-2,-6)=(10,1,5)$.  Thus, you have the following parameterisation.
$$\{(-15,-1,-1)+\lambda(10,1,5) \mid \lambda\in\mathbb R\}$$
Thus, distance between $(-5,1,-2)$ and an arbitrary point on the line is given by $$\sqrt{(-10+10\lambda)^2+(-2+\lambda)^2+(1+5\lambda)^2}$$
which you need to minimize. I mean that you have to find the $\lambda$ for which the above expression takes the least possible value.

More details, please.

@Sien Please be specific. Do you understand how the parameterization is done? Following that, how the distance of $(-5,1,-2)$ from an arbitrary point on the line is expressed. If so, we may proceed to the minimizing the distance. Are you familiar with calculus?

I'm not understanding where you're getting any of the numbers you've plugged in. And how is $\lambda$ to be figured out?

@Sien Those two are random points on your line. [See the edit.] Do you know that a line is fully determined if you know any two points on it? I found those two points just by guessing $z$ and $y$ coordinate, then putting them in the equations of the planes to get the $x$ coordinate... You could come up with different points, but that wouldn't matter. I would want to do the last part using the concept of critical points/ extrema from calculus as it's computationally easy... Are you familiar with these concepts? If not, I'll do it algebraically...
